# How can i determine the ImagePosition of the reconstructed MPR DICOM image?

Tags: dicom

I have a set of 2D images and i made an MPR over then to generate another views, now i want to save the new series as DICOM, so how can i determine the ImagePosition or the new images using the ImagePosition and ImageOrientation known of the original series?
P.S: the problem is the original series may be oriented in the x,y, and Z directions

Comment: Hi @sara-saeed, Could you tell me how can I make a MPR from series of dicom? I succeeded to show coronal side of dicoms but I can't simulate between every slice of dicom files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Section C.7.6.2 of [part 3](ftp://medical.nema.org/medical/dicom/2009/09_03pu3.pdf) of the DICOM standard defines what the Image Position and Image Orientation mean and gives an equation relating these quantities and the Pixel Spacing to the coordinates of the center of the voxel in the ith column and jth row of the slice.  The extent of the voxel in the direction normal to the image plane is given by the Slice Thickness.

So, you're given all the spatial information you need to figure out the location of each of the voxels of the original dataset in space.  Computing the Image Position and Image Orientation of the MPR images that you created is then just a matter of doing a bit of vector arithmetic to relate the location and orientation of your new MPR slices to the coordinate system of the original data.